# Is is good idea to create new project if Google OAuth consent screen Verification email not responding?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

How much time does it take for Google OAuth verification process?

> Please reply directly to this email once your project has been updated to continue with your verification request, or if you have other questions. Any new emails sent to api-oauth-dev-verification@google.com won't go to our team.

After making changes according to the recommendation and removing restricted scopes, I submitted in console and replied to email, but there is no reply after 2 weeks.

Shall I create new project and submit for verification?

Thank you!

I made changes according to recommendations, submitted changes and replied to email. and expected to get a reply but been 2 weeks without reply.

Comment: email them again and ask for a status

Comment: I did. still, no response.